# Reading orc file of Hive managed tables in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am trying to read orc file of a managed hive table using below pyspark code.

```
spark.read.format('orc').load('hive managed table path')
```

when i do a print schema on fetched dataframe, it is as follow

```
root
 |-- operation: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- originalTransaction: long (nullable = true)
 |-- bucket: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rowId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- currentTransaction: long (nullable = true)
 |-- row: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col1: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- partition_by_column: date (nullable = true)
```

Now i am not able to parse this data and do any manipulation on data frame. While applying action like show(), i am getting an error saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Include vector the wrong length
```

did someone face the same issue? if yes can you please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: `select(df.row.col1) ` does this work? In that case you can use it to flatten it, I guess.

Comment: i tried, df.select("row.col1").show(), getting same error

Answer (score 1):

It's a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16996).

You get that error because you're trying to read `Hive ACID` table but Spark still doesn't have support for this.

Maybe you can export your Hive table to normal `ORC` files and then read them with Spark or try using alternatives like `Hive JDBC` as described [here](https://github.com/Gowthamsb12/BigData-Blogs/blob/master/Spark_ACID)

Answer (score 0):

As i am not sure about the versions You can try other ways to load the ORC file.

Using SqlContext

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load(orcfile)
```

OR

```
val df= spark.read.option("inferSchema", true).orc("filepath")
```

OR SparkSql(recommended)

```
import spark.sql
sql("SELECT * FROM table_name").show()
```

Comment: i have already tried above two methods, getting the error specified in question while performing the action.

Comment: which spark version you are using ?

Comment: spark version 2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78

Comment: python version 2.7.5